# android service doesn't start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a simple service, but it seems it didn't start because neither of my `Log` has shown on the `logcat`

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("ID", "Y");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d("S", "Y");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I call that service like this:

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(service);
```

the mainfest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicetutorials"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.servicetutorials.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="label" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

what am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A) I don't think service has `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`
B) If you are starting your service onClickListener it should be
  `startService(new Intent(Activity.this, MyService.class));`
C) Make sure your `logcat` is showing `Log.d`
D) AndroidManifest.xml your service declaration

```
 <service
        android:name="com.example.servicetutorials.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"/>            
    </service>
```

I guess it should work

Covered in great detail [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

**Services have absolutely no need for an icon**

Comment: Is there a typo in (B)? `Activity.this` results in a compiler error for me.

Comment: android:name="package_name.ServiceName"   package_name did the trick!

Comment: Re icon: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#icon so a service can have an icon as well as a label. The label is visible in the Running Services tab in the Application Manager of Settings in Android 5. The icon should be too, because it's really simply retrievable through `PackageManager`: `pm.getServiceInfo(...).loadIcon(pm)`; they probably just use a cached icon of the app.